Installing Nvidia Drivers prompts black screen; nothing I've tried so far has fixed it
I've tried everything off google. And even though I resolved more errors, I did not ever fix the root problem of switching to nvidia drivers!
So, what's happening: Typical black screen after updating nvidia drivers (nvidia-535 proprietary, open, same result; same with 470)
The nuovau driver from xorg works but I think it works because the nvidia card just isn't used at all and instead the integrated amd card is doing all the lifting, and when I try to update drivers it can't figure out which gpu to use so it just doesn't work at all. During some googling I found this bug is not entirely unheard of when using Ryzen 7 cpus with nvidia graphics cards, on laptops.sudo  I also tried to brute force it with the drivers from the nvidia website. Same result. My theory is that the amdgpu drivers are just overriding any ability of the nvidia card or its drivers to be used while nouvua just makes it stay out of the way.
Laptop: ROG Zephyrus GA502DU with Geforce 1660 Ti, Ryzen 7 GPU, Lubuntu 24.04
Here's the outputs I've got
systemctl status sddm
Using hwinfo --gfx
sudo lspci -v as you can see nvidia card is detected. (I paste binned this one cause it is was super long), then I did a more specific use of lspci below
$lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA


    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] [10de:2191] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    
    05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] [1002:15d8] (rev c1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    
    05:00.7 Non-VGA unclassified device [0000]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/Renoir Non-Sensor Fusion Hub KMDF driver [1022:15e6]

so you can see that both the nvidia card and amd both are labeled "vga controller" even though what I've read tells me only one of them should be but maybe that doesn't matter. You can see that they're both detected.
$sudo lshw -C display

  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:72 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:24 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f7600000-f767ffff

again^...but you can see here that the amdgpu is the only one with a resolution and it's powering 2 monitors (laptop lcd and my monitor monitor)
jennifer@jenn:~$ nvidia-detector
nvidia-driver-535

EDIT: I found this guide to an older zephyrus laptop with hybrid gfx. Everything seemed normal until I got to here in the guide and checked my folder and
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf

Doesn't exist. This confirmed my suspicion that the nvidia card isn't really being used an the Nouveau driver is just making the card step out of the way of the AMD GPU. hwinfo --gfx says
...
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: nvidiafb is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidiafb"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: nouveau is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nouveau"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
...

root@jenn:~# glxinfo | grep "vendor"
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL vendor string: AMD

^this pretty much confirms it to me. The problem is that when I install the nvidia drivers, which should fix this. It bricks it and nothing short of reinstall works (for now, I'll be able to pick up an ethernet cable Friday so I can just try stuff from the root shell in recovery mode)
Edit:
I have shrodingers driver I swear.
root@jenn:~# dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                    535.183.01-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package

root@jenn:~# nvidia-xconfig

Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".

VALIDATION ERROR: Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
                  Device section "Device0" must have a Driver line.


WARNING: error opening libnvidia-cfg.so.1: libnvidia-cfg.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.


ERROR: Unable to find any GPUs in the system.

Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original'
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'

Running it again yields no other result. i'm going to reboot to make sure it's still safe. If you guys need anymore output please tell me, I'm throwing everything at the wall here.  To be safe I purged nvidia* and rm -r the xorg.conf. I noticed though in someone using an older zephyrus laptop they said where the nvidia config would be and mine simply isn't there like I mentioned above but despite that in my files say there are in fact drivers installed?
dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                    535.183.01-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  screen-resolution-extra                        0.18.3                                   all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel


I was able to get the nvidia drivers to work; however, it shorted my computer and took the monitor with it. They're in PC heaven. My general theories working on this problem tended to be in the same ballpark of correct as I was working on it. It is impossible to do much diagnostics now that it is completely fried but I have an idea of what happened and maybe if this is the situation you find yourself in, you will heed this warning.
A quick rundown (tl;dr at the end)

The ROG Zephyrus GA502DU is a hybrid computer in the sense that it has both amd and nvidia chipsets on board--and they are non-optional and cannot be changed.

The laptop required being plugged in all the time due to damaged pins where the battery connected to the motherboard.

*buntu will automatically switch the integrated chipset for power saving features, because the battery cannot charge it automatically defaults to the integrated chipset; however, it also would throw acpi errors

ACPI is involved in moderating the power use of components. This is important

I disabled ACPI to ignore its errors and force the install along. If you google this you will find most people say it doesn't matter that much and works fine without it. The components have their own sensors and are suppose to moderate themselves or can be moderated through uefi/bios options to modify voltage and other things

Installing the nvidia drivers failed over and over assumptively due to ACPI warnings or errors and the OS switching to integrated for power saving things but also with the new nvidia drivers and the PC forcing the use of integrated graphics due to the power issue, it only ever would boot to black screen. Nvidia drivers don't work for amd integrated cards; there's actually an interesting post about this series of laptops on a forum somewhere talking about many, many problems of using linux with hybrid laptops, especially this one. It did not solve my issues though, like researching in general, I did learn how to think about the problem.

Setting the prime profile and doing some low level stuff to essentially disable (or make a ghost of, like alive but not really alive) was difficult because the nvidia software failed repeatedly to setup the prime profiles tabs in the menus, along with other nvidia-tools/utils things. I fixed this basically though through some googling though it still perplexes me why the tools and stuff were not working, anyway

With integrated disabled, a strict edict to the computer to not use it or switch to it and not even have the option to, and ACPI disabled and a bad battery connection, the nvidia card was finally in charge of its own destiny and spoiler it dies at the end.

Lubuntu booted, I was so excited after many weeks of reinstalling and os hopping and researching and tinkering and failing it finally booted. Everything was loading up, the nvidia software was fully functional where I could see prime profiles, and on and on and on.

In charge of its own destiny, with all the checks to its power finally out of its way, and I guess perhaps a failure by the manufacturer to account for this and not tune the sensors of the component properly, nvidia drew as much power as it could and shorted my laptop. Let this serve as a warning if you have these problems on ROG Zephyrus GA502DU, you'll just have to stick with windows (where my drivers/gpu worked normally without all this effort or result.)


tl;dr
I disabled acpi and other power moderating things which were blocking the successful instillation of the drivers, forced prime profile to NVIDIA and did some low level stuff to essentially straight pipe it and remove integrated from the equation altogether, it finally worked and I was happy/proud with myself, but once it was finally in charge of its own destiny, with no checks to its power or safeguards in place, the card drew as much power as it could and shorted the laptop and my second monitor.
